# List Mock services from soapui xml using groovy

Tags: shell, groovy, soapui

Is there a way to list the mocked services from soapui xml file using groovy or shell script so that i can use those output to build the dashboard

Comment: You need to provide the context. Where the groovy script location (which you are talking about) present in the project? In a test case? or mock service? what have you tried ?

Comment: What is your use case? You may use `XmlSlurper` to parse and read the required data if it is just an xml file.